Actual response status 401, but when testing it becomes 403 (Spring Security)
I'm facing a problem of incorrect testing results. Here is my test:
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
class JwtAuthenticationAndAuthorizationWithTestsApplicationTests {
    private static final String USER_NAME = "test";
    private static final String ADMIN_NAME = "admin@gmail.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "test";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "testerUsername", roles = {"USER"})
    public void testAdminEndpointUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/test/mod")).andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }
}

Result:
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<401> but was:<403>
Expected :401
Actual   :403

My security config:
@Bean
    public Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
        return new Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint();
    }

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement(session ->
                        session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/test/all").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

And Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint implementation:
@Component
public class Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException arg2) throws IOException,
            ServletException, IOException {

        log.debug("Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Access Denied");
    }
}

I have tried this solution, but it didn't work for me.
I don't understand why I get 401 response status when manually checking entry points with Postman and 403 with junit testing
